# No text is being set once I select an Item on an Android spinner.

Tags: android

No text is being set when I select any item from a spinner. What might be the error?

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> pSelectAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(PCreate.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pNames);
    pSelectAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    selectP.setAdapter(pSelectAdapter);



    selectP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String nameSelected = pNames.get(arg2);
        pID = pMatch.get(nameSelected);
        p.setText(nameSelected);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    });
```

Comment: What is pID = pMatch.get(nameSelected);

Comment: Gives me an id to map into a hashmap that has the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here you missed to create the object of View class, Please match this line with your code, and make this change, This may help you..

```
selectP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new View.OnItemSelectedListener() {


(new View.OnItemSelectedListener() instaed (new OnItemSelectedListener()
```